# Dynamically change mySql db table

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic

I am working on a web application that manages the clients of the company. Details such as phone, address, email and name are saved for each client and there are corresponding fields in the database table where I save these details.

The user of the application has to be able to change the different details. For instance, he might decide that we need an extra field to save the fax number of the client or he may decide that the address field is no longer needed and delete it.

Using NoSql is not a option. I have to use PHP and mySql.

I have been considering using a JSON string to save database table fields but I have not come up with a solution yet.

Is altering the structure of my db table the only solution to my problem? I would like to prevent dynamically altering the structure of the db table, if possible.

Would it be a could idea to implement dynamic views? However, I guess that this would not address the necessity to insert new fields.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How large is the database?  is a JSON string a real option for you?  you don't need to really search those fields or join on them or anything?  (i mean, you can kind of search with a `like` or `regexp` but it's not the same)

Comment: Using JSON (a way to represent data) in a database (a way to represent data) is more of a last resort. I've used it once myself due to some extreme limitations, but it's not needed here.

Comment: okay.  I have done that before and it wasn't great.... I don't like having to transform the data once it's out of the database too much and that required a lot of special functions and stuff.  It worked but.. it wasn't portable or reusable.  I like @BotskoNet's answer.

Comment: There will be no joins with other tables. Just updating the data of the table, inserting and deleting rows and selecting rows to display them to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't it make more sense to have another table, let's call it 'information' which has the user_id as a foreign key?

So you have:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
user_id ...
/* necessary information */
);

CREATE TABLE information (
user_id ...
information_type /* maybe enum, maybe just string, maybe int, depending how you want to do that */
information_blob
);
```

You then retrieve the information with JOIN, and do not have to alter the table every time somebody wants to add another bit of info.

Answer (score 1):

What you need a key-value pair system for MySQL. The idea of NoSQL databases is that you can create your own schema based on key/values, using essentially anything for the value.

Create a table `special_fields` with a `field_name` column, or something named more specifically to field names. Use this table to define the available field names, and another table to store the `client_id` and `special_field_id` and then a value.

So client #1 would have an address (special_field record #1) value of "123 x street"

The only other way I can think of is to actually change the schema of a table to add/remove columns. Don't do that.

Comment: That is what I was going to suggest.  I have used that set up in the past.  It was essentially an "extra fields table"... you would have three columns, basically: `client_id + "fax machine" + "555-555-5555"` (oh, and a unique row ID, too... always)

Comment: Thanks. This is a very common pattern when a web app doesn't know what the user needs to store. Wordpress is pretty well-known for using this for custom fields, meta data, etc.

Comment: Definitely better than a JSON varchar(max) field

Comment: @BotskoNet Could you please tell me why you advise me "Don't do that"? Intuitively I agree with you but I don't know why. I guess you have implemented it like that and it didn't work out.

Comment: The application (and anything else using the database) assumes the schema never changes, the data does. There's just so much potential for breaking that "assumed-state". All apps, all versions of your app, all other devs touching your code can all share the schema and never worry about changing it on a daily basis (roughly). Plus, letting users "control" the schema like this is really bad - security problems, column naming problems, could never be a good thing for performance, etc. Adding a new column with 10 million records there will make a solid resource hit...

Comment: And yes, I've seen it done a lot. Mainly by developers who didn't really know of the better alternatives